# Coordinate Transformations - Map from one system to another

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Let:

```
// T = transpose

e1 = [1 0]T
e2 = [0 1]T 

p = [2 2]T
a1 = [2 1]T
a2 = [-2 5]T

x = [2 1/2]T
```

be a point in the [e1 , e2]-system. In the new coordinate system, the
[a1 , a2]-system, the coordinates of `x` deﬁne a new point `xp`.

What is this point with respect to the [e1 , e2]-system?

```
A = [
     2 -2
     1  4
]

xp = p + A * x;

// With respect to [e1, e2]
xp = [5 6]T
```

Thus, `xp` has coordinates `[2 1/2]T` with respect to [a1, a2]-system.

**My Question**

When we map `x` to [a1, a2]-system `x` remains the same for this system, but it changes from [e1, e2]-system's perspective?

Comment: I think the answer to my question is: yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `x` remains the same for [a1, a2]-system.